# Configuration sufficient for HD video editing

Tags: video, editing, hardware

I'm considering buying this pc for editing my HD videos.
Do you think it will be powerfull enough for editing and rendering?

- Intel® Core™  i7-4790 processor
- 16 GB Dual Channel DDR3L 1.600 MHz
- 2 TB HDD (7.200 rpm) + 32 GB mSATA Solid State-HD
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750Ti 2GB DDR5

http://www.dell.com/be/p/xps-8700/pd?oc=cdx8718&model_id=xps-8700#overrides=cdx8718:5~736438

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

This machine is sufficient in all aspects. You will certainly benefit from the i7-CPU and the additional SSD, the available RAM. Also you'll have access to graphic acceleration using the CUDA technology of the NVIDIA GPU, which will greatly reduce the time required for rendering.